# How much time it will take to charge a 4500mAh battery with a 65W charger?

Tags: battery, charging

> CHARGER INFORMATION

```
INPUT: 100-240V- 50/60Hz 1.8A

OUTPUT: 5.0V ==  3.0A or 10.0V == 6.5A (65.0W MAX)

 PDO: 5.0V == 3.0A / 9.0V == 3.0A / 12.0V == 3.0A
  PPS: 3.3-16.0V == 3.0A MAX (45.0W MAX)
```

> Battery: 4500mAh

Comment: Please provide more information, specifically on how this question relates to computing. Is it a laptop battery you're asking about? Given the complexities of modern charging circuits (which will charge at higher current when the battery is nearly empty, eventually lowering to a near-trickle when near full), and the varying battery configurations and charging circuits that are basically unique to every device, the only real answers are going to be empirical: try it and find out, or if you're trying to make purchase decisions then ask other owners/look at reviews.

Answer (score 2):

The time depends on the battery technology that you don't mention.

NiCd and NiMH can be charged with a constant current when empty.

Pb, NiZn, LiIo, LiFePO4 can be charged with a constant current until reaching a technology-dependant voltage. The battery will then determine the charge current which will dependend on battery voltage and resistance.

Your charger may exceed the charging boundaries or may rest below.

The answer therefore is:

It depends!